# How to convert readFileSync code to readFile?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to convert the following code to fs.readFile?  I'm running this on a nodeserver and need it to be async. I read the node documentation and I found it very difficult to follow.

I'm reading a file and setting it to a variable, im then saving it to the database (mongo). I can't find a way to asynchronously use fs.readFile and set it to a variable.

Here is my current undesired synchronous code:

```
  a.img.data = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname + '/imgTest/image.png'));
  a.img.contentType = 'image/jpg';
  a._id = accountId;
  a.save(function (err, a) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('saved img to mongo');
  })
```

Here is my attempt but it doesn't work:

```
await fs.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/imgTest/image.jpg'), function (err, data) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
   a.img.data = data;
});
 a.img.contentType = 'image/jpg';
  a._id = accountId;
  a.save(function (err, a) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('saved img to mongo');
  })
```

Comment: I feel like there should be a canonical answer for the callback question...

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing syntaxes.  The normal `fs` library does not deal in promises so you can't use `await`, and you do all the work in the callback:

```
fs.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/imgTest/image.jpg'), function (err, data) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  a.img.data = data;
  a.img.contentType = 'image/jpg';
  a._id = accountId;
  a.save(function (err, a) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('saved img to mongo');
  })
});
```

or you go the Promises route

```
const fsp = require("fs/promises");
try {
  const data = await fsp.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/imgTest/image.jpg'));
  a.img.data = data;
  a.img.contentType = 'image/jpg';
  a._id = accountId;
  a.save(function (err, a) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('saved img to mongo');
  })
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: in the Promises route you did: 
await fsp.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/imgTest/image.jpg'));
 a.img.data = data;
But where does data come from? It's supposed to be the result of await fsp.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/imgTest/image.jpg')); but it was never assigned to a variable

I just tried this and it said "ReferenceError: data is not defined"